# img isn't changing width?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to coding, and I'm having some trouble fitting an image to about 80% screen width.

The image is not moving despite me changing the `width: 80%` to other percentages. it is also going off the edge of the screen regardless of me putting `overflow: 0px;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;`

I've managed to figure this out before, but this code doesn't seem to be responding for some reason and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so any help is appreciated!

here's my code:

```
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <style type="text/css">
 <style>

  #title {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;                                                                                  
    display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: center;
   }

 </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black">
  <img id="title" src="http://www.vibrantandalive.com/pictures/title.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you included has two opening `<style>` tags one after the other. Does your actual code have this as well?

Comment: What do you expect `display: flex` to do? It might be helpful to read about it in more detail: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: oops! that's a mistake i made in copying and pasting the code. i'll fix that rn. also thank you @suuuriam for the link it seems i was confused on what flex did!

Comment: No worries, if you want to center the `<img>`, you need a container around it to which you apply `display: flex` and `justify-content: center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the opening css tag twice, this shoud work.

```html
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <style type="text/css">
   #title {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;                                                                                  
    display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: center;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black">
  <img id="title" src="http://www.vibrantandalive.com/pictures/title.png">
</body>
```

Comment: thank you this worked!! just to clarify, did the two style tags cancel each other out? just curious!

Comment: not exactly but browser expects to read css style only, after an opening css tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need all these css elements:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#title {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body style="background-color:black">
  <img id="title" src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: oh thank you! i didn't realize the * was a thing I could do! (again, very new at coding haha)

Comment: Yes you have loaded with alot of css property and I made your code simple and fit to the screen with 80% width and center aligned, you don't have to use flex.. etc. make it simple always.